# how to set timer when closed subviews

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiviewanimation, handshake

I tried to open two subviews and closed at time so I tried like this

```
- (void)motionBegan:(UIEventSubtype)motion withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    if(event.type == UIEventSubtypeMotionShake)
    {
        [self shakeView];
        //[self open];
    }
}

-(void)shakeView
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:2.8
                     animations:^{
                         //OPEN
                         firstView.frame = CGRectMake(0, -40, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height/2);
                         secondView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 260, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height/2);

                         // Its final location
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                         // Closed 
                         firstView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height/2);
                         secondView.frame = CGRectMake(0,230 , self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height/2);
                     }
    ];
}
```

I need two view changed positions and then come to same positions, but when I call this two methods open slow but closed very fast.

How do I set timer when Closed views?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this.

```
-(void)shakeView
{
[UIView animateWithDuration:2.8
                 animations:^{
                     //OPEN
                     firstView.frame =CGRectMake(0, -40, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height/2);
                     secondView.frame =CGRectMake(0, 260, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height/2);
                     // its final location
                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished)
 {
     //Closed

     [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{

         firstView.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height/2);
         secondView.frame=CGRectMake(0,230 , self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height/2);
     }];

 }];}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your closing part;

```
firstView.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height/2);

secondView.frame=CGRectMake(0,230 , self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height/2);
```

Is not within a animation block. Opening has a duration of 2.8 sec, but closing will execute without any duration.

Put your closing part inside another animation block.

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.4 animations:^{
    firstView.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height/2);

    secondView.frame=CGRectMake(0,230 , self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height/2);
     }completion:^(BOOL finished){
     }];
```

Comment: thanks for reply Please give me any idea how to set timer  closed part duration

Comment: @user3678584> put you closing part inside an animation block.